# calling different methods of same class using multi threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class as below with three methods

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // what code need to write here 
        //to call the specific methods based on request types
    }

    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

    public int multiply(int a , int b){
        return a*b;
    }

    public int division(int a , int b){
        return a/b;
    }

}
```

and my main class as blow
here r.multiply(), add() and division() methods will be executed sequentially, but i want to execute them in multi-threaded way hence i can get the result faster. how to call a method of a class dynamically based on inputs. how to pass to thread and how to return result from thread to calling thread.

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();

        // how to do below calculation using multihtreading
        // how to call a method and how to get result of a thread of same class
        int result = r.multiply(1, 2) + r.add(4, 5) + r.division(10, 5);
        System.out.println(result);

        int newResult = r.add(20, 50);
        System.out.println(newResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please go and read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/.  You'll understand threads a lot better if you read some more before you start trying to use them.  (Based on your first attempt ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-threading would slow down this application (because the amount of processing per step is far to small to justify the overhead of distributing the work across threads), the application probably finishes well before you perceive it anyway.

Assuming it's a simplified example you can write

```
 MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
 Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

 CompletableFuture<Integer> mult = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> r.multiply(1, 2),exec );
 CompletableFuture<Integer> add = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> r.add(4, 5) ,exec);
 CompletableFuture<Integer> div = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> r.division(10, 5),exec);

 CompletableFuture<Integer> result = mult.thenCombine(add, (multRes,addRes) -> multRes+addRest)
                                         .thenCombine(div, (total,divRes) -> total+divRes);

 int answer = result.join();
```

**UPDATE** Why use an explicitly defined Executor?

- It shows readers *how* to explicitly define an executor (the alternative is straightforward)
- By defining the Executor as a variable, you can switch between the Common ForkJoinPool (or any other executor type) by changing just that variable assignment (you don't have to refactor all of the methods). E.g.

  ```
  //ForkJoinPool common
  Executor exec = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

  //Expanding thread pool
  Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  //Just execute on the current thread
  Executor exec = (Runnable r)  -> r.run();
  ```
- By default CompletableFuture.*Async methods share the Common ForkJoinPool and so do Parallel Streams, along with ForkJoinTasks without a specific executor. Unless all members of the team think carefully about when to / not to use the Common ForkJoinPool you could end up mixing async I/O operations with CPU bound processing in the same pool accidentally.
- Also by default, the parallelism is set to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1. Which again, may or may not suit the use case at hand (for some users it might mean this example was single threaded). It is configurable via the System Property "java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", if you need to change the defaults.