# Calling a method with in run method for multi threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to consume data from a blocked queue .The consume method needs to be implemented in the run method.
I have following code which needs to implemented in run method

```
 @Override
public String consume(String lastSourceOffset, int maxBatchSize, BatchMaker batchMaker) throws StageException {
        long nextSourceOffset = 0;
        if (lastSourceOffset != null) {
            nextSourceOffset = Long.parseLong(lastSourceOffset);
        }
        if (queue.size() != 0) {
                Record record = getContext().createRecord("some-id::" + nextSourceOffset);
                Map<String, Field> map = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    map.put("fieldName", Field.create(queue.take()));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                record.set(Field.create(map));
                batchMaker.addRecord(record);
                ++nextSourceOffset;

            }


        return String.valueOf(nextSourceOffset);
    }
```

I am trying to make the above method to run in below "Run method"

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Is there any way i can call it.

Comment: i have read the post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760391/calling-different-methods-of-same-class-using-multi-threading-in-java but i am unable to implement the same

Comment: What do you mean call it? You mean set up everything so that your run method essentially does `consume`?

Comment: Ya i wanna make my run method to perform consume operation.@information_interchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a class constructor that takes in the parameters like so:

```
public class ConsumeRunner implements Runnable{

        String lastSourceOffset;
        int maxBatchSize;
        BatchMaker batchMaker;
        public ConsumeRunner(String lastSourceOffset, int maxBatchSize, BatchMaker batchMaker)
        {
            this.lastSourceOffset=lastSourceOffset;
            this.maxBatchSize=maxBatchSize;
            this.batchMaker=batchMaker;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            consume(lastSourceOffset,  maxBatchSize, batchMaker);

        }
    }
```

You construct your thread normally, except instead of the no-args constructor, you use the new custom one. Otherwise running it is the same.